# Prove that $A \cup (B-C)=(A \cup B)-(A \cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**I want to prove that**
$$
A \cup (B-C)=(A \cup B)-(A \cup C)
$$

**Here's my attempt**
$$
x \in A \cup (B-C)
\Leftrightarrow x \in A \lor (x \in B \land x \notin C)
\Leftrightarrow (x \in A \lor x \in B) \land (x \in A \lor x \notin C)
\Leftrightarrow x \in A \cup B \land x \notin A \cup C
$$
and therefore $x \in (A \cup B)-(A \cup C)$ by definition of set difference. However, I'm a bit unsure whether the following equaivance used in the proof is correct, namely:
$$
x \in A \lor x \notin C \Leftrightarrow x \notin A \cup C
$$
Because if $x$ is in $A$ it's also in $A \cup C$ regardless of whether it's in $C$ or not. Am I missing something?

Comment: $x\in A\lor x\notin C$ is not equivalent to $x\notin A\cup C$. If anything, it's equivalent to $x\notin C\setminus A$.

Answer (score 3):

The thing you're proving is false. Take $B=C=\varnothing$. Then $A \cup (B - C)$ simplifies to $A$, and $(A \cup B) - (A \cup C)$ simplifies to $A - A = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

The last biconditional is incorrect. Recall the definition of Union and the noting the meaning of "not belongs"  Use De Morgan's Law and you will see why the last statement was incorrect.